# Why does BeginReceive() not return for more than one read?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

In the code below, I make a call from `Main()` to `Receive()`, which in turn calls the `Async BeginReceive()`, and completes receiving the data in a background thread.

The Problem: For the first read, BeginReceive is succesful and appends the StringBuilder. However, when called again, the `if(bytesread>0)` condition is never reached and thus I never act on the data received. 
I want BeginReceive to deal with more than one read, and (i think this is related with the threading) I would like for the `Main()` function to be always listening for new COMMANDS from the client (not new connections, I'd like to keep the same Socket). Is this even possible?

Attempts At Solution: I added the ManualResetEvent in an attempt to stop the `Main()` function from exiting prior to the Async reading going on in another thread.

Relevant Code in Main():

```
        Receive(server); //await instructions from the client
        done.WaitOne(); //This is a ManualResetEvent.
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Method Definitions:

```
        public static void Receive(Socket server)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketArgs sockargs = new SocketArgs();
            sockargs.handler = server;


             server.BeginReceive(sockargs.buffer, 0, sockargs.buffersize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), sockargs);

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
    public static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ia)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketArgs sockargs = (SocketArgs)ia.AsyncState;
            Socket server = sockargs.handler;
            int BytesRead = server.EndReceive(ia);
            if (BytesRead > 0)
            {
                //Continue reading data.
                sockargs.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sockargs.buffer, 0, BytesRead));
                MessageBox.Show(sockargs.sb.ToString());
                server.BeginReceive(sockargs.buffer, 0, sockargs.buffersize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), sockargs);
            }
            else
            { //Do stuff with sb.ToString()



                done.Set();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your `ReceiveCallback` ever execute a second time? If not, are you sure the client has sent additional data?

Comment: Well, the client hasnt sent a ton of data, just something you can get in one read. My issue is, the second time, it should return zero bytes read, and then execute my handling code. However it doesnt seem to be reaching that point on the second read call.

Comment: You only get a zero-byte read if the client disconnects. I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/06/using-socket-as-connected-socket.html) that goes into more detail.

Comment: Okay so as it is,  what do i need to do in the main function, to keep the handler sock forever awaiting more data? I tried the manualresetevent, but it still has exits,  weirdly.

Comment: Even if the MRE didn't block (which would be the case if it was set), then `ReadLine` most certainly would.

Comment: If you want the client's receive operation to return 0, you need for the server to shutdown the socket. In the .NET `Socket` class, this looks like `socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)`. You should read any basic Winsock tutorial to learn the fundamental techniques for using sockets.

Comment: Are you aware that blocking on an event negates the benefits of async IO? Why are you using APM in the first place?

Comment: yes i am. Client (which has a rich GUI) used APM, and I know it so I used it in server too. Also, the MRE is only there to sync up the client/server. Without it, server will connect to client, and immediately try and send data before a connection is made. Also weirdly (maybe you can shed some light on this), ReadLine blocks the main thread from exiting, but the MRE doesn't.

Comment: The MRE is set, then. if you don't need async: Replace with sync and this bug automatically goes away in the process. Easier.

Comment: i figured it out! THe event needs to be Reset (MANUALLY, derp), prior to calling WaitOne()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the event so that `WaitOne` blocks again. As per the comments the event is erroneously left in a set state causing Main to exit.

Comment: Some more explanation of how this would solve the questioner's problem would not be remiss. As it stands, this looks a lot like a comment.

Comment: This is the solution as per the comments. This answer is pretty much just there to resolve the question.

Comment: I was reviewing this when I left that comment, and couldn't see the comments on the question. Remember that comments are not necessarily permanent, and while I'm sure this answer would help the OP, later stumblers-upon of this question and answer would benefit from your wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

BytesRead only returns zero when the socket disconnects. Thus, the solution to my issue is to simply handle a disconnect in the else{} section.

More information can be bound in this very helpful [article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/06/using-socket-as-connected-socket.html).

Edit: And to clarify, I left the BeginReceive() call there at the end of the if() construction, so there is "always" a BeginReceive() operation occuring.

Comment: I rearranged your post so it looks less link-only ish. Please review the changes to make sure I didn't change your intent.