# C# Socket connection can't receive more than once

Tags: c#, c, sockets, unity-game-engine, client-server

I have a server in C that send message to unity.  In Unity, I can receive data once, but when the server sends a new message, unity receives nothing.

For example: Unity can connect to server, receive the first message that said "move right" and move the camera of Unity to the right but then if the server send "move left" or anything else unity is block in the function receive which calls BeginReceive:

```
client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
```

Code of my server:

```
void connectToUnity() {
    SOCKADDR_IN sin;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(53660);
    bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    listen(sock, 0);
    printf("Connexion to unity\n");
}

void sendDataToUnity(const char * mouvement) {
    SOCKET csock;
    while (1)
    {
        int sinsize = sizeof(csin);
        if ((csock = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&csin, &sinsize)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            send(csock, mouvement, 14, 0);
            printf("Donnees envoyees \n");
            return;
        }
        else {
            printf("Rien n'a ete envoye");
        }
    }
}
```

Code in Unity:

```
public bool ConnectToServer(string hostAdd, int port)
    {  
        //connect the socket to the server
        try
        {
            //create end point to connect
            conn = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(hostAdd), port);
            //connect to server

                      
            clientSocket.BeginConnect(conn, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), clientSocket);
            socketReady = true;

            connectDone.WaitOne();

            Debug.Log("Client socket ready: " + socketReady);


            // Receive the response from the remote device.  
            Receive(clientSocket);
            //receiveDone.WaitOne();

        


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log("socket error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return socketReady;
    }

    //async call to connect
    static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket 
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection  
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Debug.Log("Client Socket connected to: " + client.RemoteEndPoint);

           connectDone.Set();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error connecting: " + e);
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Log("Try to receive");
            // Create the state object.  
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;


            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e);
        }
    }

    static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            //Read data from the remote device.  
            Debug.Log("receive callback");
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Il y a une réponse");
                
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                
                
                response = state.sb.ToString();
                Debug.Log(response);

                

                //client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
            else
            {

                if(state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                    Debug.Log(response);
                }
            }
           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The function receive is called once in the function ConnectToServer, then I tried to call again in the update like this:

```
  void Update()
    {
        if (response.Contains("right"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Move to the right ");
            float x = Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.x;
            float y = Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.y;

            DeplacementCamera.moveRight(x, y);
            response = "";

            Receive(clientSocket);
            
        }
    }
```

I have already see this post but without success or maybe I tried it in the wrong way:

[Why does BeginReceive() not return for more than one read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771483/why-does-beginreceive-not-return-for-more-than-one-read)

Edit: In the function ReceiveCallback the else is never reached.

Comment: Could you show your `Receive` method and all information needed to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

you may change your method

```
  private void SetupReceiveCallback(Socket sock)
    {
        try
        {
            DataBuffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            AsyncCallback recieveData = new AsyncCallback(OnRecievedData);
            sock.BeginReceive(DataBuffer, 0, DataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, recieveData, _socket);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
           
        }
    }
 private void OnRecievedData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            if (sock.Connected)
            {
                int nBytesRec = sock.EndReceive(ar);

                if (nBytesRec > 0)
                {

                    string Data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DataBuffer);
                    if (Data.Length != 4)
                    {
                        string JsonString = Data;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JsonString))
                        {
                            
                            try
                            {
                               //Add you code processing here
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                
                            }
                        }
                        BufferSize = 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BufferSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(DataBuffer, 0);
                    }
                }


                SetupReceiveCallback(sock);
            }
            else
               // on not connected to socket
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            
        }
    }

public bool Connect(string IP, int Port)
    {
        try
        {
           _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            //if (IsValidIP(IP))
            //{
          
            //    IPEndPoint epServer = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), Port);
            //    _socket.Connect(epServer);
            //}
            //else
            //{
         
            //    _socket.Connect(IP, Port);
            //}

            //SetupReceiveCallback(_socket);


            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return false;
    }
```